# Limiting Space between Letters

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Letter Shadows from User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470932/letter-shadows-from-user-input)

The user inputs their name and it is printed out vertically twice.  The second column is supposed to be like a shadow.  I am trying to crunch the letters in the second column (id=letters2) or limit the space between them.  Does anyone know how to do this.  Also, please view the code in MZFirefox because the rotation effect only works in that browser.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">   

function animate() {  

var txt = document.getElementById("words").value;
var area = txt;
var splittxt = txt.split("");

document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("letters2").innerHTML = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < splittxt.length; i++) {
document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML + splittxt[i] + "<br>";
document.getElementById("letters2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("letters2").innerHTML + splittxt[i] + "<br>";
}
//displays how many symbols are in text box and what is in text box
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML= txt.length;          
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = txt;          

r.clear();      
// Make our pink rectangle 
ellipse = r.ellipse(40, 15, 30, 5).attr({"fill": "#969696", "stroke": "none"}); 
ellipse.glow({width:10});  
}      

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#letters
{
background-color:yellow;
width:25px;
float:left;
}

#letters2
{
letter-spacing:0px;
display:block;
-moz-transform: rotate(80deg);  
margin-left:90px;
margin-top:80px;
width:25px;
color:#DEDEDE;
}
</style>

</head> 

<body>  

Text: <input type="text" id="words" value="" /> 
<input type="button" value="Animate" onclick="animate()" /> 
<div id='msg'></div> 
<div id='num'></div>
<div id='letters'></div>
<div id="letters2"></div>
<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; margin-top:0px;"> 
</div> 
<div id="elps" style="margin-left:100px;"/>  

<script type="text/javascript"> //all your javascript goes here  
var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael");  

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Live Long and Prosper.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to stick with [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470932/letter-shadows-from-user-input)?

Comment: Yes, but no one would answer it when I changed it to this question

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be better for you to actually provide some help with my first or second question rather than criticizing me when I am in desperate need of help.

Comment: We're not here for **you** - we're here to help if we can. I saw your original, and couldn't help - so I didn't. I saw another question (this one) and immediately recognised the code and knew I'd seen it recently - unfortunately for you I'm still unable to help.  I'm sorry that you "deperately need help", but that is not our problem

Comment: I didn't see your original, but I did see this, so I will give you a hand if I can. You want to scrunch up the letters in the letter2 div, right? If i understand you right, you could use a css `line-height`  to shorten the height between the letters. http://jsfiddle.net/c7uDm/ <-- something like this?

Comment: I am not sure, but please check if <pre> tag is helpful.

Comment: I told you I'd be back Mike...true evil never dies!!

Comment: Out of interest, why didn't you go with the CSS `text-shadow` approach to creating the drop shadow? Shall, I post my comment as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Yes please do.  I will accept your answer if you +1 my questions.  :)  I may still switch over to text-shadow.  It just all depends on what my boss wants.  I am just trying different things and you have been very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the CSS `line-height` property to change the spacing between the letters.

Here is a jsfiddle I made earlier:
jsfiddle.net/c7uDm